# Ask users if user wishes to re-run the program

Tags: java, string, methods, boolean, java.util.scanner

I wrote the following program which displays if a number is a prime and if not a prime it display its prime factors and the next prime number.

However, I am not sure how to have the program ask the user if he/she wishes to input another number.

The user must answer either `yes`, `no`, `y` or `n` using any combination of lower and upper case letters.

If an invalid answer is given, the program must be informed that the answer was not acceptable, and then be prompted again for another answer. The program will only prompt up to three tries otherwise the program will exit.

If the answer is Yes (in any allowed form), the program must continue from step in the main function.

The program is written in prototype methods because that is what is called for.

If anyone can assist a newbie with the last part, i would greatly appreciate it.

code:

```
package primefactors;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Primefactors {
    //------------------three tries check method-------------------

    public static int getNumberWithThreeTries(int m) {

        int count = 1;
        int number;
        String s = "tries";
        while (count <= 3) {
            number = getInputNumber(m); //getScore returns -1 for invalid inputs
            if (number <= 1) {
                if ((3 - count) < 2) {
                    s = "try"; //just make sure that singular /plural form in the next statme is correct
                }
                if (count == 3) {
                    System.out.println("No more tries remaining!\n");
                } else {
                    System.out.println((3 - count) + " " + s + " remaining! Try Again!  \n");
                }
                count = count + 1;
            } else {
                return number;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    //-------------------boolean try again---work in progress---------------
    public boolean askRunAgain() {
        System.out.println("Would u like to solve more problems? ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean askRunAgain = scanner.nextBoolean();

        return askRunAgain;
    }

    //----------------------------------boolen prime check method------------------
    public static boolean isPrime(int m) {

        for (int i = 2; i * i <= m; i++) {
            if (m % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


    //------------------------next prime method-----------------
    private static int nextPrime(int m) {
        if (m % 2 == 0) {
            m = m + 1;
        }

        for (m = m; !isPrime(m); m = m + 2)
                ;

        return m;
    }

    //---------------------primefactors----------------------
    public static String getPrimeFactors(int m) {
        String ans = "";

        for (int i = 2; i <= m; i = i + 1) {

            if (m % i == 0) {
                ans += i + "*";
                m = (m / i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        return (ans.substring(0, ans.length() - 1));
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------
    public static int getInputNumber(int m) {

        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter an Integer greater than 1");

        if (!n.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("That's not a number! you have ");
            n.next();
            return -1;
        }
        number = n.nextInt();

        if (number <= 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        return number;
    }
    //------------------------------main method ----------------------

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number;
        int count = 0;

        number = getNumberWithThreeTries(1);

        if (number <= 1) {
            System.out.println("Program Terminated");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (isPrime(number)) {
            System.out.println(number + ": Is a Prime Number \n\n"
                + getPrimeFactors(number) + ":  Is its prime factor");

        } else {
            System.out.println(number + " Is not a Prime number\n\n"
                + getPrimeFactors(number) + " Are its prime factors \n\n"
                + nextPrime(number) + " Is the next Prime number\n ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the getNumberWithThreeTries within a while loop, which at the end, ask if the user wants to try again.  If they say yes, then your while loop should then continue to execute again, otherwise, it should exit.

Comment: I am not 100% sure how to do so.  Any comments will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Thank for your comments, I figured out another way